# How to create an SQL Compact 2008 application

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server-ce

How can I make a SQL Compact 2008 application for the desktop?  I know how to connect to a .SDF file with SQL Management Studio 2008, but I can't figure out how to connect to it with my app.  I have seen tutorials about this and I can see in the C# code they are referencing some special namespaces, but I can't seem to get it to work.  What I did is download the Microsoft SQL Compact SDK but I get an error whenever I try to add references to any of the DLL's that came with it.  Does anyone know where I can find the correct binaries for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you [gone here and downloaded all the components](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa983341.aspx) listed (including the design tools)?

If you post the "error" you get it might be easier to diagnose your problem.

Answer (score 0):

You need to download SQL Sever Compact 3.5.

Then you could create a LINQ2SQL model (dbml) using the sqlmetal tool that
comes with the .NET SDK (and Visual Studio). Currently it is not possible
to create LINQ2SQL classes for the compact framework inside Visual Studio,
but you will be able to view and edit them.

I haven't got much time now, as I really need to get going,
but I hope this gets you started.

PS: References in my project are System.Data, System.Data.Linq
and System.Data.DataSetExtensions

UPDATE:

As for the DLL's you are referencing... I don't think they are .NET assemblies
but native win32 DLL's intended to be used by C++ developers.